# Odd coffee notation on menus

Tags: espresso, coffee-culture, coffee-shop

On a trip to Texas I've noticed that espresso drinks are listed on menu boards as "3 oz.," "6 oz.," and "8 oz.," instead of "cortado," "cappuccino," and "latte," respectively. I have not seen this notation anywhere else. Is it unique to Texas, or a new convention that is still catching on, or what?

Comment: Listing the amount might be legally required in Texas?

Comment: Unlikely, as the convention doesn't seem to apply to drip coffee, tea, etc.

Comment: Interesting. I have never seen this. Also, that wasn't exist when I was in Texas.

Comment: Is this literally 'the amount of milk to fill it to that level', so rather than any 'Italian' designation it is listing 'how much your coffee is being thinned with milk'?

Answer (score 1):

i'm wondering if this is a wee joke?
In any coffee joint in north america it's common to have a name for the size of a drink like vente, grande or small medim large, BUT these are also associated with eactly these kinds of OZ sizes

For example [on the startbucks coffee sizes page](https://customerservice.starbucks.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3113), it reads

The drink sizes we currently offer are:

- Short [8 fl. oz.]
- Tall [12 fl. oz.]
- Grande [16 fl. oz.]
- Venti® Hot [20 fl. oz.]
- Venti® Cold [24 fl. oz.]

also, i may be reading you incorrectly but
"cortado," "cappuccino," and "latte,"
are types of drinks;
oz on the other hand are sizes.

you can have any size applied to a latte for example.

???
apologies if i have misinterpretted you.

m.c.

Comment: Um... No, it's not a joke.

Comment: also Trenta® Cold* [31 fl. oz.]... ermm... is that still over a single shot? You could read small-print through that, between rest-room visits, that is... & if it was in a glass not a paper bucket... ;)